# The state cannot be updated correctly with setState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to run the following code to have the file selector input a file and manage the input file as a state in the file. But it produces output as described in the comments. I do not know the cause. How should I fix the problem?

```js
const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);

const fileSelect = (event: ReactChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  if (event.target.files === null) { return ; }
  const f: File | null = event.target.files[0];
  console.log(typeof(f)); // <- object
  setFile(f);
  console.log(f); // <- null
}

return (
<div className="flex px-1">
<input
  onChange={fileSelect}
  type="file"
/>
</div>
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: if you want see file state changes on console use ``useEffect` hook :  https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-ace-p226r8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi @BoKuToTsuZenU. I could not see the comments to which you referred in your question. But, I believe I have the solution to your problem. My code is in JavaScript. You will need to update it to Typescript. Please see my answer, and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you call setState it doesn't mutate the state immediately. You can refer to this thread here.
[Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: `f` isn't state; `f` is a local variable. `file` is the state and it's not being logged anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Typescript data types, it appears you want to save the actual file contents into state, not just the name of the file.

These lines in your code:

```
const f: File | null = event.target.files[0];
console.log(typeof(f)); // <- object
setFile(f);
```

...show an attempt to update state with type `File`, not type `string`.

Saving file contents into state can be achieved with **React.useState**. File contents can be converted to Base64 and stored in state as strings.

These demos on JS Fiddle use [React.useState](https://jsfiddle.net/kofeigen/vz0htmq8/) and [Redux Toolkit](https://jsfiddle.net/kofeigen/sgjohn5q/2/). Source code is available on SourceHut: [React.useState](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekofeigen/file-upload-usestate); [Redux Toolkit](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekofeigen/file-upload-download).

The demos use the [FileReader: readAsDataURL() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) to upload files as [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) which can be saved as **strings** (not strictly as **File** types) in an array using [React.useState](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState).

These functions are the key to saving file content:

### Read the file as a Data URL and update state

```
function processFiles( file ) {
    var filereader = new FileReader();
    filereader.onload = function onLoadCallbck( fileEvent ) {
        let dataUrl = fileEvent.target.result;
        let newFile = {
            dataUrl,
            fileName: file.name,
            fileType: file.type
        };
        setFiles( ( prev ) => {
            let list = [ ...prev ];
            let newList = list.concat( newFile );
            return newList;
        } );
    }

    filereader.readAsDataURL( file );
}
```

### Event handler for file upload field

```
/**
 * Event listener for the file upload input field.
 */
function handleFiles( event ) {
    if ( ! event.target.files.length ) {
        listRef.current.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
    } else {
        listRef.current.textContent = "";
        Array.prototype.forEach.call( event.target.files, processFiles );
    }
}
```